# Get query result preserved in the same order of query array for $in operator in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database, nosql

I have an array of `productIds` and a `Product` collection. I want to query the product collection 
for all the products in the productIds array but I want the result to be in the **same order as
the query array**. The productsIds are in a sorted order using other parameters which is not
available in the documents in Products collection, so *I cannot use a sort on product collection*.
**Is there a way to preserve the order?**
Example:

```
productIds: [362,128,4783,1,44]
```

After `db.collection('products'). find({id:{$in:productIds}}).toArray()` 
I want the documents to be in the order as that of the productIds
Currently I am getting a different order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two easy options:

1) Sort in-memory

```
const productIds = [362,128,4783,1,44];
const idAscending = (a, b) => productIds.indexOf(a.id) > productIds.indexOf(b.id);

db.collection('products').find({ id:{ $in:productIds } }).toArray()
.then(products => products.sort(idAscending));
```

2) Make separate queries

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const productIds = [362,128,4783,1,44];

Promise.map(productIds, db.collection('products').findOne);
```

Comment: I opted for in-memory sort with my own pagination..Anyway thanks